# Black box when opening the keyboard in safari with react

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs

When I click on the input, an empty space like this automatically appears at the bottom of the page. I couldn't fix it no matter what I did.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't debug a screenshot, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: could either be wrong configuration in meta tag or just css issue, pls post some code

Comment: I added index.html to the photos I can't add the code, it says it's too long